# Video tag from div- link is valid, video won't play

Tags: html, email, html5-video

I've got a video I'm trying to play in a responsive HTML email. I know the path is correct because I've been able to actually download the video through control-clicking the file image. The poster file displays fine. The controls display fine. But the play button won't actually cause the video to start.

```
<div border="0" align="center" width="80%">
<video width="50%" poster="http://www.total-partnership.com/email/PCI/brands/email_graphics/PCIcover.jpg" controls="controls">
    <source src="http://www.total-partnership.com/email/PCI/brands/video/PCIriskassessment.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGb9CFoDAzY&noredirect=1">
        <img src="http://www.total-partnership.com/email/PCI/brands/email_graphics/PCIcover.jpg" width="50%"/>
    </a>
</video>
</div>
```

No relevant CSS.

Comment: I hope the doctype is correct. Also can you show us a fiddle of it.

Comment: Video is [not widely supported](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/video/) in html email. That may be the cause, depending on the client you are using to view it.